# Display an alert on my html page by reading an array map data within the jscript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have student scores which I have stored in an array map.
I have set an option dropdown list in html with corresponding names.
All Ineed to do is that when I click on any option the an alert is displayed on the html page with the corresponding student name and corresponding score.
The html code works but the alert function does not work.
I am at a loss with what I am missing.
Please see the code below (I did it inline which is how I start working untill everything is working before I create the separate js file. I firsttried to hardcode the data (EXAMPLE-1)and that did not work. Then I tried to automate the operation (EXAMPLE-2) that did not work either.

Example-1

```
  <script>

  jGradeMap = new Map();
  jGradeMap.set("John", 55);
  jGradeMap.set("Tom", 60);
  jGradeMap.set("Kate", 70);
  jGradeMap.set("Lisa", 65);
  jGradeMap.set("Ziva", 85);

  function alertFunction() {
      document.getElementsByName(name) {
        if (name == "John") {
          alert("John's score is 55");
        }else if (name == "Tom") {
          alert("Tom's score is 60");
        }else if (name == "Kate") {
          alert("Kate's score is 70");
        }else if (name == "Lisa") {
          alert("Lisa's score is 65");
        }else if (name == "Ziva") {
          alert("Ziva's score is 85");
        }else {
          alert("invalid entry");
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

  <body>

    <select onclick="alertFunction()">
    <option>Select Name for score</option>
    <option name="John">John</option>
    <option name="Tom">Tom</option>
    <option name="Kate">Kate</option>
    <option name="Lisa">Lisa</option>
    <option name="Ziva">Ziva</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

EXAMPLE-2

```
jGradeMap = new Map();
jGradeMap.set("John", 55);
jGradeMap.set("Tom", 60);
jGradeMap.set("Kate", 70);
jGradeMap.set("Lisa", 65);
jGradeMap.set("Ziva", 85);

document.getElementById("selectName") = function alertFunction() {
    var studentname = document.getElementsByName() {
      for (var [key = studentname, value] of jGradeMap) {
           alert(key + "score is " + value);
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as this:

```js
jGradeMap = new Map();
jGradeMap.set("John", 55);
jGradeMap.set("Tom", 60);
jGradeMap.set("Kate", 70);
jGradeMap.set("Lisa", 65);
jGradeMap.set("Ziva", 85);

document
  .getElementById('foo')
  .addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log(`Name: ${foo.value}, Score: ${jGradeMap.get(foo.value)}`);
  });
```

```html
<select id="foo">
  <option disabled selected>Select Name for score</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
  <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
  <option value="Lisa">Lisa</option>
  <option value="Ziva">Ziva</option>
</select>
```

Same thing with `alert`:

```js
jGradeMap = new Map();
jGradeMap.set("John", 55);
jGradeMap.set("Tom", 60);
jGradeMap.set("Kate", 70);
jGradeMap.set("Lisa", 65);
jGradeMap.set("Ziva", 85);

document
  .getElementById('foo')
  .addEventListener('change', () => {
    alert(`Name: ${foo.value}, Score: ${jGradeMap.get(foo.value)}`);
  });
```

```html
<select id="foo">
  <option disabled selected>Select Name for score</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
  <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
  <option value="Lisa">Lisa</option>
  <option value="Ziva">Ziva</option>
</select>
```

Changes:

- Add the listener to the `change` event, not `click`.
- Instead of `option name=` use `option value=`.
- Don't use inline event listeners, it's widely considered bad practice. Instead, use `addEventListener` on the DOM node.

Comment: Thank you. This works but I am stil not able to make the output to show up as an alert on the html. Applying alert() instead of console.log() does not work here.

Comment: Thanks. It must be something to do with my browsers or system. I ran the code snippet here and it worked. I copied it verbatim into Atom and saved to my desk top and then ran it from there to another tab on this same browser and the alert popup did not happen. I also tried it on firefox and the popup did not display. At least it works here.