# Alert that pops up with student score when selecting student name from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code in Javascript and Html that needs to display an alert pop up with the selected student's score.

However, my alert pop up is not working when selecting a student's name.

Would appreciate some help on why my pop-up alert is not displaying.

```js
GradeMap = new Map();
GradeMap.set("Peter", 55);
GradeMap.set("Chris", 60);
GradeMap.set("Liz", 70);
GradeMap.set("Jim", 65);
GradeMap.set("Stacey", 85);

document.getElementById('students')

addEventListener('change', () => {
  alert(`Name: ${students.value}, Score: ${jGradeMap.get(students.value)}`);
});
```

```html
<select id="students">
  <option disabled selected>Select Name for score</option>
  <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
  <option value="Chris">Chris</option>
  <option value="Liz">Liz</option>
  <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
  <option value="Stacey">Stacey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Same Question-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778694/display-an-alert-on-my-html-page-by-reading-an-array-map-data-within-the-jscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem you used `jGradeMap` (in your JS code) which is not defined replace it by  `GradeMap`  such as this code:

```js
GradeMap = new Map();
GradeMap.set("Peter", 55);
GradeMap.set("Chris", 60);
GradeMap.set("Liz", 70);
GradeMap.set("Jim", 65);
GradeMap.set("Stacey", 85);

document.getElementById('students')

addEventListener('change', () => {
alert(`Name: ${students.value}, Score: ${GradeMap.get(students.value)}`);
});
```

```html
<select id="students">
<option disabled selected>Select Name for score</option>
<option value="Peter">Peter</option>
<option value="Chris">Chris</option>
<option value="Liz">Liz</option>
<option value="Jim">Jim</option>
<option value="Stacey">Stacey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have used your code now and the pop up still does not display.

Comment: @Kev_Dev can you show  me what the console shows to you ? you need to replace the JS code only in your code by the way.

Comment: you can use this site [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show me your code with the behavior

Comment: so in the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ohLm5wjd/ the code does exactly what I want it to do, but in my browser the pop up does not work. what could be wrong on my side could it be chrome?

Comment: I'm using chrome and it is working for me, try to use different browser and tell me what did you find and if still not working right click on the page and choose inspect elements and then get the console and run code again while console is open and tell me if you found any errors so I can help you to fix the problem.

Comment: my console is clear there are no errors, i have tried using firefox and safari but theres still no alert.

Comment: I really don't know how to help you in this case but my advice is to try the very simple example [Alert Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert) just copy and paste it in new file and name it `test.html` and open it and test if it is still not working if it is working so try to figure out what is the problem in your case, but if it is still not working you can search for the problem "Alert Not working in any browser" maybe you could find solution to your issue. I will appreciate if you could mark the answer as right answer if you could solve your problem.

Comment: I feel so silly the reason why none of it was working was i forgot to add the script for javascript in the head of my html :). Thanks for all your help really appreciate it .

Comment: Any time :) all the best